# Change column values

Tags: javascript, netsuite

I have running script and I want to know if it is possible to change the value of column using script, for example, I have a column name **department**. Under department there are different department like accounting, Sales, Marketing. I want to change the **accounting, sales and marketing** to a *code* like for **accounting I want it to be 01, sales to 02 and marketing to 03.** Thank you so much!

[Sample Column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85ylO.png)

[Sample Transaction with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBBfe.png)

Comment: Where's the code and what have you tried?

Comment: Add your codes over-here or create a jsfiddle.

Comment: [link] https://jsfiddle.net/qhqq4yhp/ . Here is the code and like what I said, I want to change the department to code( **accounting to 01** ). Thank you so much!

Comment: I included sample transaction in my post. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Arg0n sir. I already used `rec.getLineItemValue` but I got a null result :(

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't work...

Comment: @Arg0n you mean you can't run ?. I will post here the codes.

Comment: `if(search[x].getValue('debitamount')>0){
    layout += '<tr rowspan="1">';
    layout += '<td align="center" colspan="1" line-height="150%">'+(search[x].getValue('custcol_jv_accntnumber'))+'</td>';
    layout += '<td align="left" colspan="1" line-height="150%">'+ampchange((search[x].getValue('custcol_jv_accntname')));
    layout += '<br />'+(search[x].getText('entity'));
    layout += '<br />'+(search[x].getText('class'));
    layout += '<br />'+(search[x].getText('department'));
    layout += '</td>'; `

this is the code I want to change the value of department. Thank you!